# DATE() vs DATE_FORMAT() en MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, buenas-prácticas

La duda me vino respondiendo una pregunta aquí en Stackoverflow.

Se trataba de obtener solamente la fecha (sin la hora) de una columna `DATETIME`, para compararla usando `BETWEEN`.

La obtención de esa fecha se puede hacer:

- Usando `DATE`       : **`SELECT DATE(col_fecha) fecha;`**
- Usando `DATE_FORMAT`: **`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(col_fecha,'%Y-%m-%d') fecha;`**

**¿Hay diferencias en el uso de una u otra función, por ejemplo de cara al rendimiento**?

La documentación de MySQL no dice nada al respecto, de ahí mi duda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consultando el [código fuente de MySQL en las funciones de conversión de `DATETIME` a `DATE` y viceversa](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/sql_time.cc#L771) se puede observar que convertir un campo `DATETIME` a un campo `DATE` es sencillo, basta con cambiar una propiedad de la clase `MYSQL_TIME` y el trabajo prácticamente está hecho:

**[Ejemplo de conversión de `TIME` a `DATETIME`:](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/sql_time.cc#L771)**

```
void time_to_datetime(THD *thd, const MYSQL_TIME *ltime, MYSQL_TIME *ltime2)
{
  thd->variables.time_zone->gmt_sec_to_TIME(ltime2,
    static_cast<my_time_t>(thd->query_start()));
  ltime2->hour= ltime2->minute= ltime2->second= ltime2->second_part= 0;
  ltime2->time_type= MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATE;
  mix_date_and_time(ltime2, ltime);
}
```

**[Ejemplo de mezcla de datos `DATETIME` y `TIME`:](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/sql_time.cc#L1552)**

```
void mix_date_and_time(MYSQL_TIME *ldate, const MYSQL_TIME *ltime)
{
  DBUG_ASSERT(ldate->time_type == MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATE ||
              ldate->time_type == MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATETIME);

  if (!ltime->neg && ltime->hour < 24)
  {
    /*
      Simple case: TIME is within normal 24 hours internal.
      Mix DATE part of ltime2 and TIME part of ltime together.
    */
    ldate->hour= ltime->hour;
    ldate->minute= ltime->minute;
    ldate->second= ltime->second;
    ldate->second_part= ltime->second_part;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Complex case: TIME is negative or outside of 24 hours internal. */
    longlong seconds;
    long days, useconds;
    int sign= ltime->neg ? 1 : -1;
    ldate->neg= calc_time_diff(ldate, ltime, sign, &seconds, &useconds);
    DBUG_ASSERT(!ldate->neg);

    /*
      We pass current date to mix_date_and_time. If we want to use
      this function with arbitrary dates, this code will need
      to cover cases when ltime is negative and "ldate < -ltime".
    */
    DBUG_ASSERT(ldate->year > 0);

    days= (long) (seconds / SECONDS_IN_24H);
    calc_time_from_sec(ldate, seconds % SECONDS_IN_24H, useconds);
    get_date_from_daynr(days, &ldate->year, &ldate->month, &ldate->day);
  }
  ldate->time_type= MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATETIME;
}
```

Este último paso es un poco más complejo porque en caso de tener horas negativas o fuera del rango de 24 horas se recalcula la fecha.

Enlace a la [función de análisis de formato de fecha y hora (`parse_date_time_format`)](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/sql_time.cc#L833).

---

**Pruebas empíricas:**

Se pueden hacer pruebas empíricas para comprobar que la hipótesis es correcta ([ver prueba en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4g6wJhHfyFRgVgGzXnaNDE/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pruebas (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fecha datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO pruebas (fecha) VALUES
('2017-10-25 00:00:00'),
('2017-10-26 11:33:47'),
...
('2017-10-25 00:00:00'),
('2017-10-26 11:33:47');

SELECT COUNT(*) fecha
FROM pruebas p
GROUP BY p.fecha;

SELECT COUNT(*) DATE
FROM pruebas p
GROUP BY DATE(p.fecha);

SELECT COUNT(*) DATE_FORMAT
FROM pruebas p
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

**Resultados:**

```
                Mínimo    Media     Máximo
Normal         0.715742  0,966951  1.126992
DATE()         0.721084  0,958496  1.117721
DATE_FORMAT()  1.979319  2,385409  2.758417
```

Se puede observar que apenas hay diferencia apreciable entre la obtención de los datos normales y los tratados con la función `DATE()` (incluso en la muestra de 5 resultados aparentemente es más rápido el uso de `DATE`), sin embargo sí que hay una diferencia más notable a la hora de usar la función `DATE_FORMAT()`.

---

**En resumen:** tras la sobrecarga de análisis de la estructura de la consulta, flujo de resolución, etc, finalmente una conversión de datos de fecha es mucho más rápida que cualquier llamada a una función que tenga como sobrecarga adicional el cálculo del formato de texto que debe devolver.

Comment: He dejado de hacer las pruebas empíricas, parece no haber diferencia (apreciable) entre hacer un `SELECT` del campo, de la función `DATE` y del uso de `DATE_FORMAT` en una tabla en la que he insertado 50.000 valores. Creo que la mayor parte del tiempo se va en la transmisión de los resultados (aunque sea en local con el comando `mysql`). Voy a probar con varios millones de registros y alguna función que impida el envío de todos los resultados.

Comment: Gracias por la opción adicional. El resultado es prácticamente el mismo que usar `DATE()` porque las funciones de conversión (como `DATE()` y `CAST()`) lo que hacen para cambiar de `DATETIME` a `DATE` es simplemente cambiar la propiedad `time_type` de la estructura [`MYSQL_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.0/structst__mysql__time.html) de un valor [`MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATETIME` a `MYSQL_TIMESTAMP_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.0/mysql__time_8h.html#aa633db8da896a5a0cc00ffcfb7477e73).

Answer (score 5):

Yo supongo que `Date()`:  `SELECT DATE(col_fecha) fecha;` es más rápido que usar `DATE_FORMAT`, es decir.

Cuando tu usas `Date()`, no le estás pasando argumentos, el formato lo tiene definido, en cambio, `Date_format()` tiene que evaluar el formato de la fecha a cada registro, por lo que quieras o no, será más lento, y es algo que se notaría a grandes escalas de datos.

La ventaja que tiene `Date_format()` respecto al `Date()` es que puedes definir tu el formato, `Date` como tal no te permite seleccionarlo.

*Aclaro que esto es una **deducción propia**, puedo estar equivocado.*

Comment: Gracias. ¿Esto es una opinión tuya o tienes fuentes que lo sustenten? Creo que una buena respuesta debería estar basada en fuentes o en pruebas de datos.

Comment: Como he editado después, es una deducción propia, pero me parece que es algo razonable. No es lo mismo evaluar una variable a una constante. Como digo, no tengo fuentes o pruebas que lo demuestren ya que no he tenido la oportunidad aún de trabajar con grandes cantidades de datos para probar el tiempo de respuesta. Todo nace del pensamiento lógico.