# Como convertir el formato de una fecha larga a una fecha corta en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando una aplicacion completa, en la cual al revisar envios pendientes,deberá mostrar en un grid de default el folio del viaje pendiente,la fecha del dia actual y su proveedor. El problema esque desde la base SQL tomo el dato con el siguiente formato:
2018-07-03 09:02:32.000
y deseo solo utilizar el formato:
2018-07-03
utilizo la siguiente consulta para arrastrar los datos de la DB en MySQL

```
select folio as #DeViaje,
       fecha,
       proveedor 
from  TBL_Recolectores_historial 
where (enviado_SAP='0')
```

En la DB, esa columna de fecha esta con el formato datetime.

### ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar el formato que se muestra solamente modificando la consulta?

He leido las respuestas posibles que me han comentado, pero creo no he dado a entender mi problemática. En la DB, ya EXISTEN las fechas establecidas, se obtuvieron al capturar los datos.Lo que requiero es sencillamente realizar una consulta, en la columna fecha, donde en vez de obtener la fecha completa, obtenga la version abreviada, como si fuera un substring. No deseo obtener la fecha actual, deseo obtener los datos de la columna en el formato de fecha corta, para yo en mi aplicación poder manejarla como yo según requiera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuve consultando con algunos programadores en la universidad que tienen mas experiencia como data manager, y me indicaron que la adicion seria solamente CONVERT(varchar, fecha, 101)
Para que en mis consultas solo apareciera la fecha que me interesa.Tambien haciendo algunas pruebas afortunadamente no necesitare la conversion para las consultas mas sencillas al sustraer datos.

```
select folio as #DeViaje,fecha,proveedor from  TBL_Recolectores_historial where (enviado_SAP='0') and fecha >= getdate();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp
En este sitio aparecen los codigos de conversion, que necesitaré de acuerdo a como avance el proyecto, y dejo la información por si en el futuro alguien lo necesita.

Comment: si bien es cierto que toda la informacion de w3scools y otras se encuentra en las mismas proporcionadas por MySQL, en ocasiones por facilidad a la información y uso de ejemplos es más clara en las otras fuentes que en en la fuente principal y por lo mismo existen.

Answer (score 0):

> Necesitas pasar tu columna por la función [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) la cual solo tomará la parte de año-mes y día de tu columna ignorando mas no eliminando la parte de tiempo

**Ejemplo**

```
SET @Fecha = NOW();
SELECT DATE@Fecha;
```

Obtengo como resultado:

> 2020-01-31 00:31:58

Ahora si esa misma consulta la pasamos por dicha función obtenemos solo la parte que nos interesa:

```
SET @Fecha = NOW();
SELECT DATE(@Fecha);
```

> 2020-01-31

Tu consulta entonces pudiera quedar así:

```
select folio as #DeViaje,
       DATE(fecha),
       proveedor 
from  TBL_Recolectores_historial 
where (enviado_SAP='0');
```

Comment: [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/112168/29967) se aborda el problema sobre el rendimiento, puesto que también puede usarse `DATE_FORMAT` para este caso. La conclusión ha sido que es mejor usar `DATE` que usar `DATE_FORMAT` para convertir un `DATETIME` a simple  `DATE`.